# Javascript - forward zip file from server to user to download

Tags: javascript

I have this bit of code on the server:

```
const JSZip = require('jszip');

const zip = new JSZip();

// some logic to populate zip file

zip
  .generateNodeStream({ type: 'nodebuffer', streamFiles: true })
  .pipe(fs.createReadStream('out.zip').pipe(res))
  .on('finish', function () {
    logger.info('file was written out successfully');
    res.end();
  });
```

When I call the server directly via browser I do get a file for download.
I would like to integrate this into a UI.

I have a simple page with a single button, which on click call this method

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/download/'
const myFetch = (id) => {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', baseURL + id);
  element.setAttribute('download', 'zip1.zip');

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.matches('.ID1')) {
        myFetch(1);
    }
    else if (event.target.matches('.ID2')) {
        myFetch(2);
    }
    else if (event.target.matches('.ID3')) {
        myFetch(3);
    }
    return

}, false);
```

I tried several things inside of the `then` block, but I was unsuccessful to forward the zip file to the browser for download.
I seem that the `then` block does not really wait for the file to be passed from the server.

How can I pass the file to the browser for download?

Comment: Why the `fetch()`? You should just have `element.setAttribute('href',baseURL+id)`. No solution suggested in your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64369938/javascript-html-forward-file-to-user-for-download) and the identified duplicate suggests `fetch()`.

Comment: I've updated the question, please take another look.

Comment: What does the Network panel of your dev tools say when you run that code?

Comment: @Kaiido, nothing. before that, I used promise for `myFetch` and I did see the call and response from the server, but could not figure out how to forward the file to the browser for download

Comment: *When I call the server directly via browser I do get a file for download* - what is the URL you use for that?

Comment: @tevemadar same as the one used by `myFetch`

Comment: So, it is `http://localhost:3000/download/1`, and it's working. And it's absolutely not `http://localhost:3000/download/zip1.zip`?

Comment: The current code should be working if the server really returns the correct response. (any log server-side btw?) Looking at the revision history though you *were* doing something wrong in that code since `response.body` will be a ReadableStream, you can't just convert it to a string like you did. You'd need to consume the Response as a Blob and generate a blob:// URL from that: `fetch( url ).then( response => response.blob() ).then( blob => { ... element.href = URL.createObjectURL( blob ); ...` But setting the `href` to point to your server directly should work and should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

So that code should look like this:

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/download/'
const myFetch = (id) => {
//  fetch(baseURL + id)
//  .then((response) =>{
      var element = document.createElement('a');
//      element.setAttribute('href', 'application/zip, application/octet-stream, application/x-zip-compressed, multipart/x-zip,' + response.body);
      element.setAttribute('href', baseURL + id);
      element.setAttribute('download', 'zip1.zip');

      element.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(element);

      element.click();

      document.body.removeChild(element);
  //})
  //.catch((error) => {
  //  console.error(error);
  //})

  //return;
}
```

In fact I'm not sure if the append/remove (and styling) is necessary, I tested similar code in Chrome only (there it worked without them).

Comment: It used to be necessary to have the anchor in the document for Firefox, it's not anymore.

Comment: I've updated the question, please take another look. I tried your code but nothing happens